# Am I supposed to re-type my fields over and over, or am I thinking though this wrong?

Tags: graphql, apollo, prisma

I'm sort of getting my head around Apollo/GraphQL/[Prisma](https://www.prisma.io)/Yoga, but the one bit I'm always getting stuck on is, there's just so much doubling-up going on.

Say I have a schema type called `Client`, which has `title`, `firstName`, `lastName`, `email`, `phone`, `address` etc etc.

When I make a mutation, I need to type out all the fields:

```
const result = await this.props.saveClientMutation({
  variables: {
    title,
    firstName,
    lastName,
    email,
    (etc)
  }
})
```

this then goes to my actual graphQL definition in my client, where I type out all the fields again (twice!)

```
mutation SAVE_CLIENT_MUTATION ($title: String!, $firstName: String!, $lastName: String!, $email: String!) {
  login(title: $title, firstName: $firstName, lastName: $lastName, email: $email) {
    client {
      id
      firstName
      lastName
    }
  }
}
```

this then goes to the resolver in my server (which, thank god for spread operators), then to my database schema where I essentially type all the same fields a fourth time.

This just seems like a gargantuan surface area for bugs and inconsistencies. Have I thoroughly misunderstood how this is meant to work, or is there meant to be this crazy amount of re-typing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try make use of...

- [interfaces](https://graphql.org/learn/schema/#interfaces) to define types with shared fields
- [input types](https://graphql.org/graphql-js/mutations-and-input-types/) for mutations with shared fields
- [fragments](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/advanced/fragments.html) for queries with shared fields

...but you will still need to retype a lot of fields as far as I understand

An interface should throw an error at least if a type does not correctly implement it, and input types & fragments should save you some re-typing (if they can be reused).

```
# Reusable type fields
interface IClient {
    title: String
    firstName: String
    lastName: String
    email: String
    phone: String
    address: String
}

type Client implements IClient {
    # You must re-type interface items
    title: String
    firstName: String
    lastName: String
    email: String
    phone: String
    address: String
}

# Reusable mutation input variables
input ClientInput {
    title: String
    firstName: String
    lastName: String
    email: String
    phone: String
    address: String
}

# Reusable query fields
fragment ClientParts on Client {
  firstName
  lastName
}

# You can use your input type & fragment here
# although the input does change the structure from your example
mutation SAVE_CLIENT_MUTATION ($input: ClientInput!) {
    login(input: $input) {
      client {
        ...ClientParts
        id
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Cheers Edward, that all makes sense.